# Linux Almalinux - While or Array

Tags: arrays, linux, if-statement, while-loop, almalinux

I would like to realise the following in Linux-Almalinux:
So i would like to add 5 records with a new random word in it.

Problem is that following code will add N records with the same word.
How can i some how add or something or maybe some temp variabele where i can delete this after every while loop...

So when INPUT_NUMBER is 5 then it adds 5 records with 5 random different names

```
local word=$(sort -R names.list | head -1)
Local INPUT_NUMBER=${2}

while [[ 1 -le $INPUT_NUMBER ]]
do
    create_record ${word} ${Domain}
    ((i = i + 1))
done
```

Thanks in advance!

I tried to think about a solution but since im more experienced with JAVA,
these WHILE/IF is completely different in Linux and more complex.

Comment: How is almalinux relevant here? What shell are you using, `sh`, `bash` or another one? As for your solution: simply get the random word inside the loop, not outside of it

Answer (score 0):

Put N words in an array and loop over the array.

```
local n=$2
local words=($(sort -R names.list | head -n "$n"))

for word in "${words[@]}"
do
    create_record "${word}" "${Domain}"
done
```

Comment: Thank your very much for this solution!

Answer (score 0):

Untested since you didn't provide any sample input/output and `create_record` isn't a common command that most people have (I don't) but this might be what you want:

```
shuf -n "$n" names.list | xargs -I {} -n 1 create_record {} "$Domain"
```